# Por que cuando imprimes una matriz (matriz.[variable].length) devuelve las columnas?

Tags: java

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] tabla=new int [5][3];

    System.out.println(tabla.length);

    for (int filas = 0; filas < tabla.length; filas++) {
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < tabla.length; columnas++) {
            System.out.println(tabla[filas].length+" filas");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(tabla[columnas].length+" columnas");
        }
    }




}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo se que al imprimir tabla.length me da el numero de filas, pero no entiendo por que al imprimir la variable filas (tabla[filas].length) y la de las columnas (tabla[columnas].length) ambas muestran el numero de columnas. He leido por internet que dicen que se empieza a contar en la fila como si fuera cero, pero no lo termine de entender.

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/127841/edit) tu pregunta para añadir más información sobre tu duda, ¿Cuál es el resultado que tú hubieras esperado?

Comment: No sé si me consigo hacer entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por supuesto, cuando haces:

```
System.out.println(tabla.length);
```

Esto te devuelve el tamaño de la primera dimensión del array, o a lo que tu te refieres como la cantidad de *filas*. Según la declaración de tu array, esto viene siendo `5`.

Ahora bien, si haces:

```
System.out.println(tabla[x].length);
```

... en realidad no importa cual sea el valor de `x`, esto te devolverá el tamaño de la segunda dimensión de tu array, o a lo que tu te refieres como la cantidad de *columnas*. Según la declaración de tu array, esto viene siendo `3`.

De modo que no importa que la variable se llame `filas` o `columnas`, el nombre de la variable es irrelevante. Lo que importa es que al usar la variable entre los primeros corchetes:

```
// Es todo lo mismo
System.out.println(tabla[filas].length);
System.out.println(tabla[columnas].length);
System.out.println(tabla[0].length);
System.out.println(tabla[1].length);
System.out.println(tabla[2].length);
System.out.println(tabla[3].length);
System.out.println(tabla[4].length);
```

... en realidad estás pidiendo por el mismo dato: el tamaño de la segunda dimensión del array, que es `3`.